# Unbrick HTC Desire

Tags: rom-flashing, unbricking, fastboot, radio-firmware

This is my output of `fastboot getvar all`

```
(bootloader) version: 0.5
(bootloader) version-bootloader: 6.93.1002
(bootloader) version-baseband: 5.17.05.23
(bootloader) version-cpld: None
(bootloader) version-microp: 051d
(bootloader) version-main: 2.12.110.4
(bootloader) serialno: HT08MPL005xx
(bootloader) imei: xxx
(bootloader) product: bravo
(bootloader) platform: HBOOT-8x50
(bootloader) modelid: PB9920000
(bootloader) cidnum: T-MOB003
(bootloader) battery-status: good
(bootloader) battery-voltage: 4109mV
(bootloader) partition-layout: Generic
(bootloader) security: off
(bootloader) build-mode: SHIP
(bootloader) boot-mode: RUU
(bootloader) commitno-bootloader: dirty-365c78d6
(bootloader) hbootpreupdate: 11
```

I have downloaded RUU `RUU_Bravo_Froyo_HTC_WWE_2.29.405.14_Radio_32.49.00.32U_5.11.05.27_release_224699_signed`
Which is for a different radio. So I downloaded `32.49.00.32U_5.11.05.27` and did:

```
fastboot flash radio radio.img
```

and received this output:

```
sending 'radio' (26112 KB)...
OKAY [  4.836s]
writing 'radio'...
FAILED (remote: image update error)
finished. total time: 8.362s
```

according to google that means that the radio.img is corrup. I took it from the mirror of http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=687464 I have found an other radio.img which has the same version as the RUU from http://www.generalfiles.me/download/gs61d0834bh32i0/bravo.radio-5.11.05.27-signed.zip.html but that did make the desire shake three times when it was writing the radio and then hang.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the story -- but what exactly is your question?

Comment: Lol, well the radio flash failed, and because of that the ruu failed. so how to proceed to have a working htc desire again?

Comment: Ah, OK. Always good to mention the question explicitly :) As from the error message, could it be the `radio.img` is corrupt? You could e.g. check [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575) for an alternative source.